# Doing feature selection properly?

Tags: r, r-caret

I would like to use the feature selection capabilities of library(caret) however struggle somehow to

1. implement the function based on random forest regression and
2. labeling the output plot with corresponding variable names

What I tried is:

Given the sample data:

```
     set.seed(2014)
     a<- rnorm(1000, mean = 10, sd = 3)
     b<- rnorm(1000, mean = 15, sd = 2)
     c<- rnorm(1000, mean = 20, sd = 2)
     d<- rnorm(1000, mean = 25, sd = 2)
     e<- rnorm(1000, mean = 30, sd = 2)
     f<-rnorm(1000, mean = 45, sd = 2)
     g<-rnorm(1000, mean = 50, sd = 2)
     h<-rnorm(1000, mean = 60, sd = 2)
     depvar<-rpois(1000, exp(3+ 0.5*a - 0.25*b+0.3*c))
     data<-data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,depvar)

library(mlbench)
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
```

define the control using a random forest selection function

```
     control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method="cv", number=10)
```

run the RFE algorithm

```
     results <- rfe(data[,1:8], data[,9], sizes=c(1:10), rfeControl=control)
```

This takes a while. But it works fine. Adding additional variables and expanding the number of rows to 10000 for example just takes forever. Therefore Im not sure whether this is really the random forest regression rather classification...Is there a way to improve the runtime with a similar set up given around 20 numeric variables?

```
     ggplot(results)
```

or ordinary

```
    plot(results, type=c("g", "o"))
```

I also coudn`t find anything with regard to the x-axis labels. Is there a way to add the correspondung variables rather than 1,2,3...

Thank you in advance

Comment: For your second question: `ggplot(results) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:8, labels = names(data)[1:8])`

Comment: @ shadow thank you. that looks much better :-)

Comment: It does to the RFE procedure 11 times and the R RF implementation is not very efficient. The variable importances scores are a good part of that computational time. I would suggest using parallel processing. First, see how much ram you are using now. If you are using X MB and want to split it across 3 workers, the total RAM costs is 4. See [this page](http://topepo.github.io/caret/parallel.html)

Comment: @ topepo thank you for this advice. I will try that. But according to your knowledge my code itself is fine? Or have I confused it with something else? That is just my worry, that there might be a similar implementaion for feature selection of a numeric dependent variable with ca. 20-25 covariates using random forest. I´m new to the field of machine learning and always doubt :---)

Comment: Yes. I dropped n down to 100 and it ran fine for me. You might consider modeling the sqrt or log of the counts; those might be better behaved and are less likely to skew the RMSE values.

Comment: ctually my dependent variable is transformed in sqrt however i use for the feature selection flow as shown above the unstransformed one, because I dont know how to include "prediction^2" in the upper flow.without untransforming it the RMSE is far off...do you know where to untrasform the srqt(dependent variable) using the rfeControl & rfe ?